# Windows 7 - Disable Close Program/Debug Program Dialog, yet crash dump and notify the user

Tags: c#, crash-dumps, crash-reports, windows-error-reporting, custom-error-handling

I'm developing a commercial Windows 7 desktop application (somewhat shrink wrap, but not quite). The application has both Windows Service and a WPF User Interface components. In the event that our application fails at a customer site we want to be able to capture information about the runtime environmnent, including a crash dump of our processes to a dump location. That information could then be forwared to our support personnel upon request  for further investigation. We also want to turn off any *Windows Error Reporting* and *Send To Microsoft* dialogs that might popup as a result of the failure.

The important thing is that we only want this to affect our application processes. We don't want to affect some global setting that will change the way all other applications on the customers desktop report fatal errors.

I'm looking for some suggestions and best practices for doing this sort of thing in a shrink wrap application.

Comment: In order to do this you need to catch any unhandled exception. At this point you send yourself any information you want. There are third-party libraries that make this extremely easy.  As to those other dialogs they will still be displayed.  An alternative is you could also of course subscribe to that information.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that. I have AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException setup for that, as well as Dispatcher.UnhandledException. However there are some exceptions that can't be handled. When those occur I get those pesky dialogs from Microsoft which I do not want.

Comment: As already indicated its unlikely will be able to handle every single exception that happens.  Its also unlikely you will be able to prevent those dialogs on a user's computer from being shown.

Comment: I just randomly found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2011/07/19/debug-diagnostic-tool-1-2-released.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your responses. These are all things I've already looked into. I guess I should have stated that in my post. I was just hoping someone could point me in the right direction with regard to doing this the right way. Sounds like I'm stuck with the dialogs and will have to look into the Microsoft Error Reporting subscription services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know how to do this is by subscribing to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event. There you will be able to use the Win32 API function [MiniDumpWriteDump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create your own minidump file. Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dondu/archive/2010/10/24/writing-minidumps-in-c.aspx) to see a good example. Also, there is the [ClrDump](http://debuginfo.com/tools/clrdump.html) library.

Before you exit from your UnhandledException handler, call [Environment.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) and you shouldn't see any more Windows error dialogs.

I have not actually used these minidump libraries myself yet, but I will soon. Hopefully this answer will at least give you a few keywords that you can plug into Google.

Comment: Thanks, I did run across that. I'll look into it futher. My biggest issue is those pesky Microsoft dialogs. Though I did find that, if I'm so inclined, I can sign up with Microsoft's Windows Error Reporting service and actually collect my crash artifacts from their website. I'll have to run that by our product owners.

Comment: @KyleLib - You might as well push to subscribe to the Windows Error Reporting service in combination of handling any specfic exceptions you feel are the most important and sending the minidump files for investigation.

Comment: @KyleLib Theoretically if you call Environment.Exit() in your unhandled exception handler, the error reporting service dialog won't show up.